# Do all tags have associated tag badges?

Tags: support, tags, badges

I tried to look at my progress towards a [space-shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-shuttle) tag badge but there does not seem to be one for that.  Are they manually created? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag badges exist only for those tags with at least 100 questions about the subject.

As of this very second, that tag has 97 questions. So go ask 3 more questions and the badge will be yours!

Comment: Yeah, that's usually recommended...

Comment: I might take a gander and see if some questions are missing that tag, though. Only where appropriate.